# Configuring additional spring configuration metadata for list-nested properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have the following model:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("example.foo")
class Foo {
 
  private String name;
  private List<Bar> bars;

  public static class Bar {

    private String url;
    private String type;

  }

}
```

I have configured properties for top-level class like this (in `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json`):

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "example.foo.name",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "description": "The name of foo"
    },
    {
      "name": "example.foo.bars",
      "type": "java.util.List<com.example.Foo.Bar>",
      "description": "These are bars of foo"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I add metadata for `Bar.url` and `Bar.type`? I tried using something like `example.foo.bars[].url` but it didn't work.

Comment: Same problem with a Map<String, Component> where Component is a custom class with properties name "expression" and "enabled"

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have getters and setters in both Foo and Bar classes. This configuration worked for me (I am using Lombok to generate getters/setters):

```
@ConfigurationProperties("example.foo")
@Getter
@Setter
class Foo {

  private String name;
  private List<Bar> bars;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  public static class Bar {

    private String url;
    private String type;

  }

}
```

Metadata generated by spring-boot-configuration-processor:

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "example.foo.name",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "sourceType": "com.demo.Foo"
    },
    {
      "name": "example.foo.bars",
      "type": "java.util.List<com.example.Foo.Bar>",
      "sourceType": "com.demo.Foo"
    }
  ]
}
```